# sampling 2-D numpy array using another array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a pretty big numpy matrix (2-D array with more than 1000 * 1000 cells), and another 2-D array of indexes in the following form: `[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],...,[xn,yn]]`, which is also quite large (n > 1000). I want to extract all the cells in the matrix that their (x,y) coordinates appear in the array as efficient as possible, i.e. without loops. If the array was an array of tuples I could just to

```
cells = matrix[array]
```

and get what I want, but the array is not in that format, and I couldn't find an efficient way to convert it to the desired form...

Comment: `matrix[xy[:,0],xy[:,1]]`?

Comment: or `matrix[tuple(xy.T)]`  Not sure which is more efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your array into a tuple of arrays like this:

`tuple(array.T)`

This matches the output style of `np.where()`, which can be indexed.

`cells=matrix[tuple(array.T)]`

you can also do standard numpy array slicing and get Divakar's answer in the comments:

`cells=matrix[array[:,0],array[:,1]]`